# Leaflet Popup Form: Include Leaflet latlong values in popup form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a popup form using Leaflet and would like to include the eventLatLong values as part of the params that are submitted.
So I draw a poly or drop a marker and the popup should appear with a form where the user enters a name. This name needs to be persisted with the draw event co-ordinates.

This is the code I have so far and have spent hours trying to figure this out. I very new to front end stuff like JQuery, Ajax and JS in general, so any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    eventLatLong = e.layer._latlng;
    var polyEvent = drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
    var popupForm = '<form class="simple_form business_form" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/create_section" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post" _lpchecked="1"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">\n' +
        '    <h2>\n' +
        '<input id="coords" type="hidden" value="">\n' +
        '        <div class="input string required thing_part_name"><label class="string required control-label" for="thing_part_name" id="name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label><input class="string required" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="thing_part[name]" id="thing_part_name"></div>\n' +
        '        <div class="form-actions">\n' +
        '            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add New Poly">\n' +
        '        </div>\n' +
        '        <br>\n' +
        '    </h2>\n' +
        '</form>';
    polyEvent.bindPopup(popupForm, {
        keepInView: true,
        closeButton: true
    }).openPopup();

    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

All I had to do was pass `theData` value via jquery's `val` function.

```
<script>
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {

    var polyEvent = drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);

    theBounds = JSON.stringify(e.layer.toGeoJSON())

    var popupForm = '<%= j render "path/to/form" %>';

    polyEvent.bindPopup(popupForm, {
        keepInView: true,
        closeButton: true
    }).openPopup();

    $('#bounds').val(theBounds);

    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```